# C# - File Modification Detected

Tags: c#, csproj

Hello anyone who can help.

I have my program take the .csproj file and parse it into an XDocument. I am then adding a `<Content>` element so that my newly created xml file will be included with the output directory. When I run my program, the File Modification Detected window pops up asking me to reload my project. Is there a way in C# to do this for me when it runs through this?

This is how I am opening the document:

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlDocument.InnerXml);
            var itemGroup = xDocument
                .Nodes()
                .OfType<XElement>()
                .DescendantNodes()
                .OfType<XElement>()
                .Last(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ItemGroup");
            var contentElement = AddProjectContent(filePath, xDocument);

            itemGroup.Add(contentElement);
            xDocument.Save(projectXml);
```

Comment: please be more specific?

Comment: so, you have code in the same project that is manipulating the csproj file or is it an external tool for updating csproj files? I've never had to programmatically manipulate a csproj file before, so some details on your use-case would be helpful.

Comment: Made edits to my question.

Comment: What does the code to open the file look like?

Comment: Would it be better to add a post compile step to copy the XML file(s) instead of changing the csproj file?

Comment: I would I go about that?

Comment: @DougDawson "I've never had to programmatically manipulate a csproj file before"...lol...me neither!

Comment: I mean, unless you all know how to programmatically include a file in the output directory without updating the .csproj.

Comment: @JamesMcKinney can you please [edit] post with information on what you trying to achieve? It is generally better to ask "I want to do ... and I tried ... but it does not ...". Skipping first part that explains what one's actual goal is often (like in this case) makes question confusing and strange - see [XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In this particular case it sounds perfectly valid to get "file changed" notification when file indeed changed, there are ways to wildcard-include files in MSBuild projects but to suggest need the actual goal.

Comment: There is no csproj file in output directory at all. Which file do you want to get in the output directory and for what purpose?

Comment: [Specify build events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: So in my code, I create an XML file. That gets elements added to it and then is saved in a folder in my project. However, the XML file is not included in the project. My question is: Is there a way to include this XML in my project without having to right-click on it in my Solution Explorer and say “Include in Project”? Is there code I can write that does this for me? @Alexander Petrov